# Step Function: Split outsput of upstream SF into batches to parallel call next SF

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I've been scowering Step Function(SF) documentation but no luck so far.

Essentially we have a SF with one lambda.  When that lambda completes we sync invoke another SF with lambda's output as payload.

Lambda outputs a huge array of values, it's placed in SF context and next step in SF is invoke another SF, passing output of lambda as payload.

My question is, is it possible to chunk up that payload, and, within the first SF, parallel invoke multiple second SF with a different portion of chunked output for each parallel invoke?

Comment: I don't that chunking logic would be possible out-of-the-box. But your first lambda could output the data in a chunked manner (or a second lambda could chunk it) and then you can have a parallel invoke for each chunk.

Comment: The problem with that is our call to 2nd SF is synchronous - we need to wait on response.  This second SF could run for 10 seconds, it could run for 20 minutes - so we can't invoke from within lambda, it has to be done at the infrastructure layer.

Comment: So? Nowhere did I say to invoke anything synchronously from your lambda. Chunk the data in a lambda and then let SF call other lambdas in parallel based on those chunks (probably using the `Map` function of SF).

Comment: The step function is calling another step function, not lambda.  I want to be able to chunk the lambda output up, and invoke parallel step functions based on number of chunks.

Answer (score 1):

[**Update - late 2022:**  Add a 3rd option using the new `ArrayPartition` intrinsic chunking function]

[Map States](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html) expect an `Iterator` (in your case State Machine #2) and `ItemsPath` (an array of elements to be processed in parallel).  <del>Step Functions cannot chunk the data natively.</del>  How do you split your dataset into an array you can pass to `ItemsPath`?  Here are <del>two</del> three options:

#### [**Update**] `"States.ArrayPartition($.ItemsPath,4)"`

The `ArraryPartition` [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-arrays) will natively chunk your input items array.  Add a `Pass` state that calls this intrinsic function.  Use the `Pass` state's output as the Map state's `ItemsPath`.

#### `ItemsPath: [chunk0-array, chunk1-array, ...]`

As @luk2302 suggests, have a Lambda task split the data into sub-arrays.  Set the Map's `ItemsPath` to the chunking lambda's `ResultsPath`.

#### `ItemsPath: [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]`

Alternatively, don't chunk the data.  Instead, add a hardcoded array of indexes `ChunkIndex: [0,1,2,3]` (the values don't matter, only the length is used) and a total chunks `ChunkCount: 4` attribute to your input.  A `Pass` state can add it. `ChunkIndex` is the field that is iterated.  Each `Map` iteration receives the full dataset but only works a subset of it, which each can calculate based on its `ChunkIndex`, `ChunkCount` and dataset length.

By default each `Map` iteration receives as input only its iteration item, so rework the input using [Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html#input-output-parameters) and the [Context object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html#contextobject-map) to send the whole payload to each iteration:

```json
"States": {
  "MapState": {
    "Type": "Map",
    "Parameters": {
      "ChunkIndex.$": "$$.Map.Item.Index",
      "FullInput.$": "$"
    },
    "ItemsPath": "$.ChunkIndex",
    "Iterator": <State Machine #2>
    ...
```

Comment: This wasn't what I was after.  Solved it by creating multiple `Map` states inside a `Parallel`.